# Connecting the database and the model using Angular.js

Tags: php, javascript, codeigniter, angularjs

I have an app that's completely a 'round trip' app, as AngularJS would put it. I'm setting up a sidebar to use AngularJS but I'm a bit confused about next steps. Have the following example placed on my page just as a starting point (one of their homepage examples, no big win here):

http://jsfiddle.net/w5LKa/

What I'd like to do is figure out how to get data from my database rather than hard coding this:

```
$scope.todos = [{
    text: 'learn angular',
    done: true },{
    text: 'build an angular app',
    done: false
}];
```

I'm happy to set up a table with just these two field for purposes of essentially completing this tutorial. From what I've read, a good way to go seems to be configuring an API, but that isn't something I really want to dive into right now. I just have normal models that return arrays, as specified by a single query.

Can anyone shed some light about how I can do this? I'm working in Codeigniter as my server side framework.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get your data with $http

For example:

```
$http({
   url: "some url here",
   method: "POST",
   data: {"key":"value"}
}).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    $scope.data = data;
}).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    $scope.status = status;
});
```

Or you can use $resource, the documentation is [here](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource.%24resource)

Comment: So would that 'some url here' just be a controller that returns model data as json? Is that a fair way to set it up server side?

Comment: Yes, the url can point to a controller's action that returns json. That's the way i use it. :)  If you only want the json data you can use the method: "GET" instead of "POST".